# Car shudders above 45 mph after a spin out into a ditch

Tags: suspension, steering, mitsubishi, alignment

I spun out in freezing rain and ended up in a ditch. I was doing 60 down to 45 when it went all the way around and on to the shoulder, which was soft dirt and buried the front tires. My vehicle is a 2003 Mitsubishi.

Since then I have had shuddering at speeds above 45 and more steering play. What may be the cause? I thought maybe tires or alignment. I haven't been driving it because if it's something more serious I can't afford to fix it right now.

Any suggestions as to what it may be?

Comment: Unbalanced wheels and/or alignment should definitely be checked.

Answer (score 3):

Your suspension is bent up and is a big mess.  Goto a mechanic and get an estimate before it flies apart and injures you or innocent bystanders.

I can see a wheel shaking, off camber and out of alignment while you drive down the road.  This is not trivial.  Imagine only one of your front brakes working well and you have to panic stop for a crosswalk filled with kids.

## Hurry, call a tow truck and have it taken to a shop.

Comment: I think the first two paragraphs can be done without. Probably not wrong, but it really doesn't matter what the problem is or is not at this point - someone who knows what they're doing needs to look at the car before it's driven again, period.